# In ServiceStack OrmLite, how to update table with multiple join table?

Tags: c#, web-services, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I am writing a Servicestack update query with join multiple tables in C#.  I have searched the web and gone through all the related documents and site but not able to find enough details regarding update with join query.

I would like to update the One table with join the three different tables and where clause. I have tried all the ways by entity framework but not able to do it. I can do it by Db.ExecuteSql(SqlQuery) but I would like to do it by Entity Framework. My query is below.

I want to update the UpdateStatus of HeartRate Table join with PatientDetails, DeviceSession, PatientSession and HeartRate tables and where clause is HeartRate.timestamp =  ‘@starttime’ and PatientId =  ‘@PatientId’

SqlQuery =

```sql
UPDATE HeartRate  SET UpdateStatus = 1
WHERE  HeartRateID IN ( SELECT hr.HeartRateID
FROM PatientDetails pd join PatientSession ps on pd.PatientDetailsId = ps.ByPatientId
 join DeviceSession ds on  ps.PatientSessionId =  ds.ByPatientSessionId     join HeartRate hr on  ds.DeviceSessionID = hr.ByDevSessionID
 WHERE
  pd.PatientId = '@PatientId'
  AND
  hr.Timestamp = '@starttime'
  order by hr.Timestamp Asc )
```

I need something like below (it's wrong and incomplete).

```cs
Db.UpdateOnly(
    new HeartRate { UpdateStatus = 1  },
    ps => new { ps.UpdateStatus  },
.SqlJoinBuilder<DeviceSession, PatientSession>((ds2, ps) => ds2.ByPatientSessionId == ps.PatientSessionId)
.Join<PatientSession, PatientDetails>((ps2, pd) => ps2.ByPatientId == pd.PatientDetailsId)
.Where<HeartRate, PatientDetails>((lthr2, pd2) => (lthr2.Timestamp == @starttime) && pd2.PatientId == PatientId)
.OrderBy(lthr2 => lthr2.Timestamp));
```

Answer (score 0):

//Try this one

```
var model = from v in Db.HeartRate
                  where
                  (
                      from pd in Db.PatientDetails
                      join ps in Db.PatientSession on pd.PatientDetailsId equals ps.ByPatientId
                      join ds in Db.DeviceSession on ps.PatientSessionId equals ds.ByPatientSessionId
                      join hr in Db.HeartRate on ds.DeviceSessionID equals hr.ByDevSessionID
                      where pd.PatientId == PatientId && hr.Timestamp == starttime
                      select new { HeartRateID = hr.HeartRateID }
                  ).ToList().Contains(v.HeartRateID)
                  select v;
        foreach (var item in model)
        {
            item.UpdateStatus = 1;
            Db.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Comment: Hi vicky thanks for quick reply,

I have already done by this old way but I would like to do by entity framework.

Comment: Thats true. But I would like to learn the entity framework as in below link. https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/wiki/Release-Notes